# Dynamically style substring of text within a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, styling, textblock

So, I have a WPF `RichTextBox` that will be bound to a long line of text.

What I want to do is use a set of two `TextPointer`objects, so that at any given time, the text between the two pointers has a style applied to it. (For example, change the background/foreground color of the text.) as the user moves the selections. Once the text is no longer between the two pointers, the style must reset to the original style.

The desired behavior is similar to (though not the same as) the way that you can click and drag to highlight/select text on a website, for example. Instead of clicking and dragging (the user should NOT be able to do this, I will be programatically determining the endpoints.)

I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. I know that I can apply the required styles to a `<Run></Run>`, but I can't figure out how to get a certain substring of text from within the control and apply (as well as remove) the `Run` tags to it programatically.

An ideal solution would be to change the style that is applied by the select method. I am a little wary of doing this (if it even can be done) as I am not sure if it is possible to disable selection from the user (without disabling the mouse) and still have programmatic selection available to me.

Comment: try to explain with an image. moving a selection of text is already available in RTB.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I think you originally were talking about a `TextBlock`, not a `RichTextBox`. If the solution absolutely requires a `RichTextBox`, you'll need to look into finding a usable RTF parser somewhere.

One thing you could do is use the RTF or HTML controls.

Or, you could use the code below, which I wrote with a gun to my head (actually, I wrote it to see if I could). It's arguably a sin against MVVM, but you can close your eyes and pretend that the `<Bold>` etc. tags are just some arbitrary markup language, not XAML.

Anyhow: When the desired range to be formatted changes, update the `FormattedText` property and raise `PropertyChanged`.

C#

```
namespace HollowEarth.AttachedProperties
{
    public static class TextProperties
    {
        #region TextProperties.XAMLText Attached Property
        public static String GetXAMLText(TextBlock obj)
        {
            return (String)obj.GetValue(XAMLTextProperty);
        }

        public static void SetXAMLText(TextBlock obj, String value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(XAMLTextProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert raw string into formatted text in a TextBlock: 
        /// 
        /// @"This <Bold>is a test <Italic>of the</Italic></Bold> text."
        /// 
        /// Text will be parsed as XAML TextBlock content. 
        /// 
        /// See WPF TextBlock documentation for full formatting. It supports spans and all kinds of things. 
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty XAMLTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("XAMLText", typeof(String), typeof(TextProperties),
                                                new PropertyMetadata("", XAMLText_PropertyChanged));

        //  I don't recall why this was necessary; maybe it wasn't. 
        public static Stream GetStream(String s)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            return stream;
        }

        private static void XAMLText_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is TextBlock)
            {
                var ctl = d as TextBlock;

                try
                {
                    //  XAML needs a containing tag with a default namespace. We're parsing 
                    //  TextBlock content, so make the parent a TextBlock to keep the schema happy. 
                    //  TODO: If you want any content not in the default schema, you're out of luck. 
                    var strText = String.Format(@"<TextBlock xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">{0}</TextBlock>", e.NewValue);

                    TextBlock parsedContent = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(GetStream(strText)) as TextBlock;

                    //  The Inlines collection contains the structured XAML content of a TextBlock
                    ctl.Inlines.Clear();

                    //  UI elements are removed from the source collection when the new parent 
                    //  acquires them, so pass in a copy of the collection to iterate over. 
                    ctl.Inlines.AddRange(parsedContent.Inlines.ToList());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Error in HollowEarth.AttachedProperties.TextProperties.XAMLText_PropertyChanged: {0}", ex.Message));
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion TextProperties.XAMLText Attached Property
    }
}
```

Other C#

```
//  This `SpanStyle` resource is in scope for the `TextBlock` I attached 
//  the property to. This works for me with a number of properties, but 
//  it's not changing the foreground. If I apply the same style conventionally
//  to a Span in the real XAML, the foreground color is set. Very curious. 
//  StaticResource threw an exception for me. I couldn't figure out what to give 
//  XamlReader.Load for a ParserContext. 
FormattedText = "Text <Span Style=\"{DynamicResource SpanStyle}\">Span Text</Span>";
```

XAML

```
    <TextBlock
        xmlns:heap="clr-namespace:HollowEarth.AttachedProperties"
        heap:TextProperties.XAMLText="{Binding FormattedText}"
        />

    <TextBlock
        xmlns:heap="clr-namespace:HollowEarth.AttachedProperties"
        heap:TextProperties.XAMLText="This is &lt;Italic Foreground=&quot;Red&quot;&gt;italic and &lt;Bold&gt;bolded&lt;/Bold&gt;&lt;/Italic&gt; text"
        />
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I was essentially asking how to turn a `TextBlock` into a `RichTextBox`. I've edited my question accordingly to respect sanity.

Comment: @Airhead Sanity is overrated. My answer does it with a `TextBlock`.